# how to paste multiple file that is more the 20,000 files containing one column in one file?

Tags: shell, awk, paste

I have multiple files (around 25000 file contains only one column), the name is like b-1.txt, b-2.txt, b-3.txt, .......,b-24999.txt, b-25000.txt. So, I want to paste all 25000 files data in one file, after that, I want to take an average over row. But, When I am using paste command it is giving me an error too many files open.
I have use following given command:

```
paste b-*.txt > 1_term.txt  
awk '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sum=sum+$i;} m=sum/NF; print  m; }' 1_term.txt > square_average.txt
```

So, Please help how can I paste many files in one?

Comment: I believe the answer in this post will be helpful. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205642/combining-large-amount-of-files

Comment: Do all your files have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to concat all the files first:

```sh
seq 1 25000 |\
xargs -I{} cat b-{}.txt |\
awk '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sum=sum+$i;} m=sum/NF; print  m; }' > square_average.txt
```

If you still want to do it you can use the same method:

```sh
seq 1 25000 | xargs -I{} cat b-{}.txt > 1_term.txt
```